# php loop through submitted form fields

Tags: php, forms, field

I'm trying to set up an email response from a form that will send back the data that was submitted. So far, I have

```
$message= '';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $message .= $key . ': ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
```

but that shows all fields, not just the ones that have a value. Is there a way to show only name and value from submitted fields?

Comment: thats where an if statement comes in to play

Answer (score 0):

Best place to look is at the isset command -- [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Basically pseudocode is:

```
//$message initialize
//foreach of the POST values as key value
//if the value isset, then
//concatenate (.=) to message
```